# LEFT JOIN ON a dynamic column

Tags: mysql

I have two tables. One containing the fields season_start and season_end which are integers (1-12).

My second table has a column called month which also contains integers (1-12) and another column called season, containing the relevant season associated with each month.

I can successfully join these two tables and retrieve the start and end associated season, but also want to find the season in the middle if applicable.

My current code is:

```
"SELECT * FROM `table1` as m 
LEFT JOIN `table2` as s 
ON m.season_start=s.month 
OR m.season_end=s.month
WHERE latin IS NOT NULL 
$qFilters 
GROUP BY latin 
ORDER BY common ASC 
".$limit." ";
```

Is this possible. Im thinking i may need to run a separate query first potentially?

Comment: Mind the SQL injections, see [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/kxeMNJ325arnTpT24rUnge/4)  blind injections are possible after or in the `ORDER BY` clause which you should be aware off..  The demo generates `SELECT * FROM DUMMY_TABLE ORDER BY 1 ASC , (SELECT SLEEP(5)) DESC# ` as blind SQL injection and notice the execution time `Execution time: 5001ms `

Comment: `SELECT * ... GROUP BY latin`  is generally a wrong SQL to write as that is not how you should **not** use [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) i advice you to read [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use between  between m.season_start AND  m.season_end 
in JOIN clause

```
SELECT * 
FROM `table1` as m 
LEFT JOIN `table2` as s  ON s.month between m.season_start AND  m.season_end
WHERE latin IS NOT NULL 
........
```

anyway you should not use php var in sql code  you area t risk for sqlinjection

and as suggested  by Raymond Nijland you should not use group by without aggregation function  (this produce unpredcitable result for mysql < 5.7 and raise  by default an error for mysql >= 5.7)

Comment: *"anyway you should not use php var in sql code you area t risk for sqlinjection"* Indeed the location (in/after the `ORDER BY` clause) makes it a (bit) harder as a **blind** SQL injection is required.

Comment: @RaymondNijland  ..  $qFilters is not at the end of the code  ..  is in the middle  (between  where and order by .... )

Comment: oh i was talking about the `$limit` variable i even didn't notice the other variable (`$qFilters `) because of the missing syntax colour highlighting..

Comment: .. @RaymondNijland  .. anyway at least this time i  have not used  .. "archaic English word"..

Comment: The $limit variable is a constant string "LIMIT x, y or z etc" based on an if statement and not a user inputted variable, so It should be OK?

Comment: this could be right for $limit  ...but not for $filter

Comment: i also doubt that this is correct @AndyKing as `SELECT * .. GROUP BY latin` is generally wrong SQL to write..

Comment: @RaymondNijland   correct answer  updated  with your suggestion too